# Isomorphism of simple real quadratic field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $u$ and $v$ be real roots of $x^2 - 2$ and $x^2 - 4x +2$, respectively.  Let $\mathbb{Q}(u)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(v)$ be the simple field extensions over the rationals.  Show $\mathbb{Q}(u) \cong \mathbb{Q}(w)$, please.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Try again writing with LaTeX if possible.

Comment: More importantly, finish writing out the rest of the sentence. Or is "show that" supposed to be before $\Bbb Q(u)\cong\Bbb Q(v)$? This is true for all quadratic polynomials, and is an easy consequence of the quadratic formula. (In fact it's an equality not just an isomorphism.)

Comment: @anon: Not "true for all quadratic polynomials". We'd need to add "irreducible" to get field isomorphisms, and equality holds here but not e.g. for $x^2 - 3$ and $x^2 - 2$ when viewing the simple extensions as occurring in a common algebraic closure.

Comment: I don't know English very well, and I'm trying to explain to you with the help of translation sites, sorry for that. My question is; Let u and w be real roots of equations x^2 - 2 and x^2 - 4x + 2 respectively. Show that Q(u) and Q(w) are isomorphic

Comment: @hardmath If the quadratic polynomial is reducible then both roots are rational and $\Bbb Q(u)$ and $\Bbb Q(v)$ are both equal to $\Bbb Q$. Otherwise they are both equal to $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{\Delta})$ where $\Delta$ is the discriminant of the polynomial. No? You are probably thinking of higher-degree polynomial situations.

Comment: @anon: If one is reducible and one is not, the field extensions are not isomorphic, but if both are irreducible (or both reducible) they are.  You claim "an equality not just an isomorphism", which is true of these two extensions, but not in all generality.

Comment: @hardmath, are you saying that $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)\cong\Bbb Q(\sqrt3)\;$ , for example?

Comment: Don, I think hardmath thinks *I'm* saying that. Obviously though what I am actually saying that if $u,v$ are roots of any given quadratic polynomial, then $\Bbb Q(u)=\Bbb Q(v)$... | Edit: oh, I just realized that "$ve$" in the original problem was the word "and," not two variables, so OP is talking about two polynomials, and my original comment is not applicable.

Comment: A pity you edited your question to turkish *after* it was already clear in english,  @kpss2014

Comment: @DonAntonio: Good point.  These are not isomorphic as field extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$, though of course they are as vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: That's one of the very few things I understood (or thought so) from the original question, @hardmath: that the intention was isomorphism as fields.

Comment: @kpss2014, the roots of $\;x^2-4x+2\;$ are $$\frac{4\pm2\sqrt2}2=2\pm\sqrt2\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$$ so $\;\Bbb Q(v)\subset \Bbb Q(u)\;$ . Now use these both are rational vector spaces of dimension two to show equality (which is more than isomorphism) .

Comment: @anon: Ah, now I understand what you were saying!

Comment: I've already failed 3 times in class of this question. I am trying to understand it but i can't. If you can show me the full solution, i would appreciate it.

Comment: Why is the topic on hold ? How can I fix it ?

Comment: Check carefully my comment above, @kpss2014 : It only uses some very basic algebra and some linear algebra, which you must know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $\,\ f(x) = x^2-4x+2 = (x-2)^2 - 2 = X^2 - 2 = F(x),\,$ so $w$ root of $f$ $\,\Rightarrow\,$ $w-2$ root of $F$. This observation tells you how the isomorphism must be defined.

Comment: How do you know what you're hinting at? Did you understand what the question says? Could you then please tell us all?

Comment: I'm sorry, i did not understand your hint, can you explain a little bit more please ?

Comment: @kpss2014 Why did you accept this as an answer if you didn't understand it?

Comment: @DonAntonio The version of the question that I read, though lacking in formatting, had fairly clear denotation to me.